# how can I apply configuration on google composer? ( core.dag_concurrency, core.parallelism )

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I use Google Composer. 
Image version : composer-1.7.0-airflow-1.10.2
Python Version : 3

I need to more parallelism and dag_concurrency.
I changed that configuration on google cloud console (composer page)

- core

  - max_active_runs_per_dag :20
  - dag_concurrency : 100
  - parallelism : 200

After check composer web. I see the airflow webpage ( Admin -> configuration) configuration text is changed
but I tested it. composer concurrency and parallelism limit are still the same.

how can I apply this configuration?

Comment: How did you test that your configuration were not applied? Could you try to set a smaller `parallelism` (1 for example), launch 2 tasks at the same time, and check if the 2 tasks are run simultaneously? Just to be sure that the config is not applied even if web UI said so.

Comment: I make a pool then I run a dag ( this dag has a lot of task and tasks are long execution time ) on that pool but after I write this question. I found a solution. Link : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations

Comment: Parallelism automatically scales to the number of nodes. So I Increased the number of nodes.

Comment: Can you please explain this in an answer? I had the same question and found the same page but it's very unclear. So `gcloud composer environments run $ENVIRONMENT --location $LOCATION variables -- --set core-dag_concurrency 100` and similar for `core-parallelism`? Or set celery-something via the web UI? A Google Groups post claims the doc is wrong and "All celery configs EXCEPT celery-celery_app_name, celery-worker_log_server_port, celery-broker_url, celery-celery_result_backend, celery-default_queue, celery-celery_config_options should be updatable in environments version composer-1.0.0".

Comment: I try to almost the same action but it's doesn't work. my solution is increased the number of nodes. I guess if you add a node, Parallelism, concurrency is changed that it increases by 5 regardless of it's setting the configuration.